# Access a function in js

Tags: javascript

I have a function in my separate js file called hello().

On my page I have this js:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//do hello fnc</script>
```

How can I get the on page script to call the function in my main js file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it in the `src` attribute of another script tag, *before* referring to any of its functions in this script.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='main.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  hello();
  // Anything defined in previously included js files like main.js
  // is now available, as well as anything defined on this page.
</script>
```

Comment: as a sidenote `type='text/javascript'` is no longer necessary

Answer (score 0):

Load the external file first and call the function:

```
<script src=external.js></script>
<script>
  hello();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the external js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyOtherFile.js"></script>
```

And then wherever in you code you want to call the funciton:

```
<script type="text/javascript">hello();</script>
```